# Leakage in power spectral density estimation

Tags: dft, power-spectral-density, signal-power

What does it mean for a power spectral density exhibiting leakes from one frequency bin to other.

I am reading a book which states the following:

"Often the time series we use as input for our algorithm will have a non-zero DC average, which
may even slowly change over time. Such a DC average will show up in the first frequency bin
(m = 0) of the resulting spectrum. If a window function is used or the average changes over
time, it will also leak into adjacent frequency bins, possibly masking low-frequency signals."

Could somebody explain what does this mean? Why does a window leak power into adjacent frequency bins?

I also read the following which has probably a similar connection and it would be good to get an explanation on this as well:

"If we simply take a stretch of length N out of a time series containing a sinusoidal signal and
perform a DFT, we will most likely find that the sinusoidal signal which we might naively expect
to result in a sharp peak in only one frequency bin, will instead show up as something ugly, The reason is that the DFT implicitly assumes that the signal is periodic, i.e. that the time series
of length N repeats itself infinitely in a cyclic manner. If the frequency of the sinusoidal input
signal is not an exact multiple of the frequency resolution fres, i.e. does not fall in the exact
center of a frequency bin, this assumption is not true, and the DFT will ‘see’ a discontinuity
between the last sample and the first sample due to the cyclic continuation. That discontinuity
spreads power all across the spectrum"

What does it mean for DFT to "see" a discontinuity as written above"?

EDIT:After accepting answer:

I ran a MATLAB simulation (code below) in which the frequency of sinusoidal is exactly a multiple of resolution of the PSD and thus falls directly at the center of a frequency bin, still there is leakage into neighboring bins (3 to the right and three to the left of this bin in which the sinusoidal lies). This spilling gets more and more resolved as I increase the window length. Which would seem to suggest that even the frequencies that fall directly at the center of frequency bins leak into the adjacent frequency bins and the amount of leakage will depend on the shape of the window and the length of the window. Is this understanding correct?

MATLAB code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PSD Estimation%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


close all;
N=50; %number of periods

Fs= 4096;
snr=10;

M=256; %length of FFT

Fres=Fs/M;

Mul_factor=20;

F_c=Fres*Mul_factor;  %in Hz%

Window_length=128;

Overlap=floor(0.4*Window_length);
x=0:1/Fs:N*(1/F_c);
y=sin(2*pi*x*F_c) + 1/sqrt(snr).*randn(1,length(x));

[ppx,w]=pwelch(y,Window_length,Overlap,M,Fs);


figure;
hold on;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,y);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(w,ppx);
hold off;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could somebody explain what does this mean? Why does a window leak
>   power into adjacent frequency bins?

You can think of frequency bins as imposing an artificial frequency grid which allows only certain frequencies to fit nicely within it (producing a sharp peak) and all other frequencies are smeared across adjacent bins thus producing spectral leakage.

This means that only those frequencies that are centered exactly on bin frequency will not produce leakage.

Since the bandwidth of a bin (i.e frequency resolution) is simply the 
sampling rate divided by the dft length, we can conclude that only frequencies that are exact integer multiples of the frequency resolution will not produce spectral leakage.

For example, if the sampling frequency is 8000 Hz and dft length is 1024, the frequency resolution is computed as

```
 frequency_resolution = 8000 / 1024 = 7,8125 Hz
```

So, if your signal contains frequencies which are integer multiples of 7,8125, you'll get
no leakage (e.g 1*7,8125, 2*7,8125, 3*7,8125 and so on)

If, however, your signal contains a frequency that is somewhere between 2 adjacent bins, you'll get spectral leakage, which I think is intuitive because no single bin can
fit that frequency component exactly.

UPDATE (trying to answer the comments below):

It's true that windowing does introduce some additional leakage on its own. But even if you don't use windowing at all (which corresponds to a rectangular window), you'll still get spectral leakage (provided that the frequency under examination is not an integer multiple of the frequency resolution). 
In fact, since using a rectangular window (no window at all) produces the worst leakage, using overlapping windows other than the rectangular helps reduce the spectral leakage.

So, why do we have spectral leakage in the first place?

Remember that DFT assumes that a signal is periodic. Since the frequency resolution is  fixed (e.g 7,8125 Hz in the example above) for every bin, which in this case corresponds to exactly 1024 samples, we can see that a single bin can hold exactly one cycle of a 7,8125 Hz frequency , 2 cycles of 15,625 Hz frequency, 3 cycles of 24,4375Hz frequency and so on. This is true for every bin, which means that there'll be no discontinuities either within a bin or between adjacent bins.

However, if we now change our frequency to something that fits between two bins, things change. This new frequency will take either more (or fewer) than 1024 samples (one or more cycles), which means that we'll get discontinuities either within a bin or between neighbouring bins and this in turn creates spectral leakage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But each bin also has a range of frequencies if we talk about the power spectral density in the continuous frequencies, (digital or analog frequency), then why would say a freuency very near the centre of centre of a frequency bin produce the spectral leakage, is it because we don't actually have a real calculated estimate for this nearby freuency? And hence it is approximated which has an inherent roll off?

Comment: Or could it be that in essence the windowing operation is a convolution of the actual signal PSD with the magnitude sqaured window, when the window is exactly the centre of the frequency bin it's main lobe is contained entirely in the bin,however anything off the centre and the main lobe itself is not contained in the bin and hence the spilling to other bins?

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, So we could say that there are two sources of spectral leakage, one is the resolution itself (defined by the sampling frequency and FFT size) the other is the window shape and size. So even if a frequency is indeed at exactly the centre of a bin it could still leak into other bins because of the spectral leakage of the window. Is this understanding correct.

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, In a sense, but note that windowing will not add spectral leakage if the frequency is just right. it will only affect the amplitude somewhat.

Comment: let's suppose I just have sinusoid that maps exactly at the centre of a bin. So would the bins adjacent to this bin show amplitudes? Suppose I am using a rectangular window which is known to have higher side lobes

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, you'll still get a single peak, because your sinusoid will fit perfectly within that rectangular window (this is easy to visualize).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I have added an EDIT section in the question, it seems what we concluded here regarding the sinusoid  fitting entirely within  a bin if the frequency of sinusoid is an exact multiple of the resolution doesnt follow the simulations. This is exactly what i simulated but there is still leakage in the adjacent bins, details in the question added with MATLAB code. Let me know of your thoughts on this. It looks to me that the window still decides the leakage even for frequencies centered at the bins

Comment: @ dsp_user For the time being I have re-opened the question to welcome thoughts on this.

Comment: any thoughts on the new findings I list in the comments above and EDIT segment of the question

Comment: Also, I don't see any distinct side lobes in your graph. It's still one wider main lobe.

Comment: The waveform frequency is 320Hz. I think having the same size of FFT and window should be no restriction to verify that if a sinusoid Frequency  is exactly at the center of a frequency bin, it still spills out. More overlap is required to decrease the variance of the estimate, I don't see any issue with variance being high in these plots. Anyway that still doesn't solve the resolution problem  Also hampers independence of windowed sections.I have also tried resolution down to 4Hz, still the spectrum spills to nearby bins.

Comment: my point is that resolution of "representation" is decided by sampling frequency and FFT size, however resolution of "resolving" frequency is decided by window main lobe, as long as window main lobe does not fit into the representation resolution, there will be spilling into adjacent bins, even if the frequency is centered at the frequency bin as in this case.

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, can you show us those distinct side lobes that you're seeing?

Comment: I dont see the sidelobes I just dont see the main lobe fitting into the frequency bin even when  the carrier frequency is centered at the bin

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, But this could be due to the FFT computation (and the windowing as well) producing round-off errors so your main lobe won't be exactly one thin line. Having a better frequency resolution will help resolve this, won't it?

Comment: I have went all the way upto 4Hz frequency resolution. I think the issue is that the estimated PSD is nothing but convolution of PSD of the sinuoid (mainly an impulse at Fc=320Hz) and the magnitude squared of the window FFT. When this convolution happens in this frequency bin then since the main lobe doesnt fit into 1 bin(for hamming window) hence it spills out even for frequency at centre of the  bin. Since convolution with impulse mainly places the spectrum of the window at the centre of frequency bin which doesnt fit in it

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, so use a window that fits in a single bin. The rectangular window produces the narrowest main lobe at the expanse of the higher noise floor. Also, don't use any overlapping to reduce the effect of windowing as much as possible.

Comment: sure, but there is still the dount in my mind if the Fc is an integral multiple of frequency resolution, does the window shape and length decide whether it fits into the bin or not? This is what this reputbale text says: Heinzel G., et al. - Spectrum and spectral density estimation by the DFT, including a comprehensive list of window functions and some new flat-top windows

Comment: @Dsp guy sam, yes, windows do matter and I did mention that in my answer. So perhaps what this discussion really comes down to is , everything else being equal, frequencies that are an exact multiple of the frequency resolution will produce a sharper peak than if we're dealing with frequencies that are located somewhere between bins. Let's leave it at that :)

Comment: agree :-) Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106672/discussion-on-answer-by-dsp-user-leakage-in-power-spectral-density-estimation).  Please continue any more discussion in the chat room.